# How to revive an angular scope after destroy?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I would like to recompile an inner scope after it was destroyed.

I am using a recompile function to help, which is "transcluded" as true.
Whenever I want to destroy the inner scope, it also destroys the parent(outer) scope.

How can I avoid deleting the parent scope while keeping this recompile function unchanged?

```
  function compile() {
      transclude(scope, function(clone, clonedScope) {
           previousElements = clone;
          $el.append(clone);

            $timeout(function () {

              scope.callBack();
    alert("Df");
}, 0);
    });
  }


 $scope.callBack = function(){

      var elem = document.getElementById('test');
      //This code kill the test div, but also the parent scope
      //Can i only kill the test div scope?
   angular.element(elem).scope().$destroy();
  alert("dd");
}
```

Here is the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/MePu8BipkkdHV0IEatbo

Comment: You really shouldn't destroy a scope unless you were the one who created it.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not the way to achieve what you try to. What is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

It is destroying the parent scope, because you are never actually creating a child scope.

You could try adding `scope: true` to the `kcdRecompile` directive.

```
app.directive('kcdRecompile', ['$parse','$timeout', function($parse, $timeout) {
  'use strict';
  return {
    transclude: true,
    scope: true,
    link: function link(scope, $el, attrs, ctrls, transclude) {
...
```

That would give `kcdRecompile` its own scope.

If you want `kcdRecompile` to have the parent scope, but its transcluded content to have its own scope, you can call the transclusion function with `scope.$new()` instead of `scope`.

```
app.directive('kcdRecompile', ['$parse','$timeout', function($parse, $timeout) {
  'use strict';
  return {
    transclude: true,
    link: function link(scope, $el, attrs, ctrls, transclude) {
      var previousElements;

      //compile();

      function compile() {
        transclude(scope.$new(), function(clone, clonedScope) {
...
```